# \partpage doesn't fit onto the slide

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer to write a presentation which is split into several parts. The title of one part is too long to fit on one single line, so there should be a line break.
However the command `\partpage` displays the text on one single line. I have the impression that the issue is related to `\insertpart`, since the same behavior happens as well for this command.

Furthermore I noted that the problem disappears if I use pdflatex, which is however not possible for my presentation since I have many .eps figures.

Here is a minimal example which reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

 \part{very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long part title}
 \frame{\partpage}
 \frame{\insertpart}

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You might have a look to [our start page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436): it will help you to familiarize with the site.

Comment: You can try `\documentclass[hyperref=breaklinks]{beamer}` but imho it would be better to use pdflatex and `\usepackage{epstopdf}`. This will convert your eps-files on the fly (if your system is not to old).

Comment: Using the option `hyperref=breaklinks` solved the problem. `\usepackage{epstopdf}` did not work, maybe my system is indeed too old.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `\documentclass[hyperref=breaklinks]{beamer}` but imho it would be better to use `pdflatex` and `\usepackage{epstopdf}`. This will convert your `eps`-files on the fly (if your system is not to old).